# Creating sheet with hyperlink

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I am using the code below, to copy the "Template" worksheets and rename it based on the cell from the "Master" worksheet starting from A5 and also copy the cell value to the newly created worksheet.

It creates the worksheets.

I would like to add the hyperlink from the "Master" when creating the worksheet so that when I click on cell A5. Let's says A5 value is "243", it will go to the worksheet of "243".

```vb
Sub AutoAddSheet()

    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Master").Range("A5")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
           .Name = MyCell.Value
           .Cells(2, 1) = MyCell.Value
        End With
    Next MyCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :). **1)** You asked two questions here. It's best if you stick to one question at a time. It's easier on everyone that way. That said, you can edit this question and post a new one about the hyperlink (and please provide more clear detail.) **2)** *however when I add another column in "Master", there was an error as it could not check for duplicate* - Can you please be more specific. It's not clear what the issue is from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create the hyperlinks, add the following line just before your `Next myCell`:

```
MyCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=MyCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & MyCell.Value & "'!A1"
```

Comment: YowE3K - Thank you so much!